# Vue custom block produce error when an empty loader added to .use clause of webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-4, vue-loader

If there is a custom block in vue file. E.g.

```
<router3333>
    path: /:category/:segment
</router3333>
```

It will be compiled and work fine with vue loader configured as the only one in the .use clause [image: https://i.imgur.com/BQxmrcF.png]

If i add another loader into use clause that do exactly nothing for example whole loader

```
module.exports = function (source) { return source }
```

Compilation will fail with error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (24:17)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./my-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
|
> path: /:category/:segment
```

The output of vue-loader in both cases is same

```
import { render, staticRenderFns } from "./xxxc.vue?vue&type=template&id=0067048f&"                                                                                                       01:13:55
import script from "./xxxc.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&"
export * from "./xxxc.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&"


/* normalize component */
import normalizer from "!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js"
var component = normalizer(
  script,
  render,
  staticRenderFns,
  false,
  null,
  null,
  null

)

/* custom blocks */
import block0 from "./xxxc.vue?vue&type=custom&index=0&blockType=router3333"
if (typeof block0 === 'function') block0(component)

export default component.exports
```

So just adding an loader that do nothing in `use` clause make custom block fail. Whats happening here and how to avoid it ?

Here is repro https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-4dqmy
If in nuxt.config set vuetify.treeShake: true - it will do what is described here, e.g. add another loader to use clause and it will cause error. The loader code itself doesn't matter as it happen with empty loader too.

Comment: Could you provide the related webpack config section?

Comment: @MaxSinev not using webpack directly, but rather via nuxt. And the relevant change to add new loader is done via api.

vueRule.use.unshift({
      loader: require.resolve('./loader'),
      options: this.options
    })

Comment: @MaxSinev i had added a repro link into issue

Comment: The error pops up whether you add the loader or not. The repro does not contain any my-loader.

Comment: @MunimMunna yes, the error popups whether i add new loader to use clause or no - no error. Disable treeShake and there wont be error. Thats the exact point. The repro contains vuetify-loader added, but the loader content isnt important at all, it could be replaced with empty loader e.g. my-loader with exact same result like i said .

Comment: What do you want the custom block to do?

Comment: @MunimMunna its already used by nuxt-router module. https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module
So the thing is, that it ends up that it dont work with vuetiyf loader. And the reason isnt in vuetify loader itself, but rather the fact that it just added as second loader into use clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats happening here ...?

The answer is pretty simple - because you have another one loader for `vue` files(that's why even `vuetify-loader` fails your build), and it can be proved with [`vue-loader` source code function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/c359a38db0fbb4135fc97114baec3cd557d4123a/lib/loaders/pitcher.js#L30) which is responsible for this. It just checks number of loaders and decides to add `import` statement for a custom block or just pass empty string [[code block]](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/c359a38db0fbb4135fc97114baec3cd557d4123a/lib/loaders/pitcher.js#L158).

> ... and how to avoid it ?

Vue-loader has docs section for the custom blocks functionality.
You can just create a **new rule** with `blockType` query param to process your custom 
`router3333` block code:

```
rules: [
  // ...
  {
    resourceQuery: /blockType=router3333/,
    loader: require.resolve('./my-loader')
  }
  // ...
]
```

So as you can see you should use your block tag as type in the code above.

And if you don't want to do anything for now with your custom block content just return an **empty string** from your loader function.

[Vue-loader Custom Blocks](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/custom-blocks.html#custom-blocks)

Comment: Thanks :) That code piece from vue-loader look exactly what i was looking for,  i didnt digged into vue loader code to find out it (

Comment: @Aldarund And there was also the same internal issue with `cache-loader` for vue files and they added kind of exception for that case(in the function from my link in the answer) https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1394 :)

Comment: yes, i noticed it in code. Not very robust solution to hardcode ignored loaders like this :)